# Windows Update error 80246008 windows 7 Sp1 x64

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008

Background Intelligent Transfer Service is Missing & Not listed

The steps I've found and tried have not helped

- Microsoft FixIt, (says it can't repair)
- sfc /scannow (found nothing)
- Add BITS to Regedit

Still I can’t find BITS in the services in Administrative tools.

Any idea how to add Background Intelligent Transfer Service  to the services in adminstrative tools?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you have BITS issues:

```
C:\Users\André>err 0x80246008
# for hex 0x80246008 / decimal -2145099768
  WU_E_DM_FAILTOCONNECTTOBITS                                    wuerror.h
# A download manager operation failed because the download
# manager was unable to connect the Background Intelligent
# Transfer Service (BITS).
# 1 matches found for "0x80246008"
```

Repair Windows 7 by doing an [Inplace Upgrade](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).

Insert your Windows 7 DVD to the DVD drive, run setup.exe and select "upgrade".

[image]

Comment: Hi magicandre1981,Thank you for the solution you posted. But I need a solution to fix it without upgrading the windows since I will lose many changes settings if I upgrade my windows.

Comment: no, with the upgrade all programs, setting stay and are not touched.