# 80246008 error when trying to download windows 10

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade

Windows 10 decided to start downloading, except Windows Update spent about 2 hours saying 0% complete on the download. I then got a code 80246008 error, how do I fix this? Also the page suggested shows a solution designed for windows 7, I'm running Windows 8.1 and do not have installation disks for Windows.

Comment: Check this :
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-update-error-80246008#1TC=windows-7

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Update error 80246008 windows 7 Sp1 x64](http://superuser.com/questions/637569/windows-update-error-80246008-windows-7-sp1-x64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went and looked at the list of updates which Windows wanted to install. I then went and manually installed one of the important updates for Windows, by copying and pasting the name of the update into a search engine. This lead me to the necessary Microsoft site to download the update. Once the update had installed, I restarted my computer, ran DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth. After that Windows was able to go ahead and install Windows 10 automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I received this on a series of machines. the most effective solution I found was to download the Windows 10 ISO and then use Rufus (http://rufus.akeo.ie/) to put it onto a USB stick. Alternatively you can burn the ISO onto a DVD as per normal.

Once your Windows 8.1 machine has booted up to the desktop normally, run the SETUP program from the Windows 10 disk. This will upgrade your machine as per normal.

I only successfully used the Microsoft/GWX/Windows Update procedure on one PC. On all the others I had a variety of issues, but all upgraded successfully using the Windows 10 media.

Also make sure your Antivirus Product is Windows 10 certified. I had this issue with Mcafee Endpoint Security 10.0 which was causing Windows 10 to lockup. I made sure I removed this prior to my next upgrade which also fixed some problems.

Answer (score 1):

The error 80246008 means `WU_E_DM_FAILTOCONNECTTOBITS`:

```
//
// MessageId: WU_E_DM_FAILTOCONNECTTOBITS
//
// MessageText:
//
// A download manager operation failed because the download manager was unable to connect the Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS).
//
#define WU_E_DM_FAILTOCONNECTTOBITS      _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x80246008L)
```

So, you have issues with your Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS). run the services snapin (`services.msc`) and make sure that the service is not disabled.

Comment: Got a 2147024894 error when trying to start BITS

Comment: is this the correct error code? I can't find such an error code.

Comment: Search  2147024894 error BITS

Comment: you miss the **minus**. -2147024894 =  ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. Run **sfc /scannow** or **DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth** to detect corrupted or missing files.

Comment: sfc / scannow said there was corrupted files but they could not be fixed

Comment: I got a 0x80240021 error when trying to run DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth with Administrator privileges

Comment: this is WU_E_TIME_OUT. So Windows can't download the good files from WU. Look inside the CBS.log which files can't be downloaded/restored.

Comment: The error in the log is 0x80240021 - CSI Payload Corrupt amd64_prncacla.inf_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.17415_none_95dd5540d57f8c01\Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB Repair failed: Missing replacement payload.

Comment: ok, point DISM to the install.wim of Win8.1 to get this repaired: **dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:WIM:D:\sources\install.wim:1 /LimitAccess** (replace D with your DVD/mounted ISO drive letter)

Comment: I have to re-image windows?

Comment: try the DISM command first.

Comment: This requires me to make an ISO drive using a computer running a healthy version of Windows 8.1? Is there a different way I can fix the problem like downloading the necessary files manually?