# How do I fix this manifest error in my ChueckSUR.log?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

My windows update isn't working. I've been following [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619779(v=ws.10).aspx) guide and its been great for fixing almost all the errors in my `CheckSUR.log`, but I can't figure out how to fix the last error. Here is the contents of the log:

```
=================================
Checking System Update Readiness.
Binary Version 6.1.7601.22471
Package Version 26.0
2016-04-22 08:04

Checking Windows Servicing Packages

Checking Package Manifests and Catalogs

Checking Package Watchlist

Checking Component Watchlist

Checking Packages

Checking Component Store
(f) CSI Manifest All Zeros  0x00000000  winsxs\Manifests\amd64_microsoft-windows-t..es-workspaceruntime_31bf3856ad364e35_7.2.7601.23095_none_3e5e6e7736f1a2a2.manifest  amd64_microsoft-windows-t..es-workspaceruntime_31bf3856ad364e35_7.2.7601.23095_none_3e5e6e7736f1a2a2    

Summary:
Seconds executed: 135
 Found 1 errors
  CSI Manifest All Zeros Total count: 1

Unavailable repair files:
    winsxs\manifests\amd64_microsoft-windows-t..es-workspaceruntime_31bf3856ad364e35_7.2.7601.23095_none_3e5e6e7736f1a2a2.manifest
```

The key line being that unavailable manifest file at the end. The problem is, I don't know where to find that manifest file so I can run `SURT` on it.

How can I fix this error? I'm on a Windows 7 machine version 6.1 with service pack 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open regedit, go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\ComponentDetect\amd64_microsoft-windows-t..es-workspaceruntime_31bf3856ad364e35_0.0.0.0_none_a65dcbedddc9e6dc` look which KB number is shown for version `7.2.7601.23095`. Now download the MSU file for this update from Microsoft Download center, [place the MSU file into](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/joscon/2010/05/26/using-checksur-and-update-packages-to-fix-corruption/)  `C:\Windows\CheckSUR\packages` and rerun the checkSUR tool.

If this doesn't work, install the update [KB2966583](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2015/07/23/the-new-and-improved-checksur/) and run the command `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /Scanhealth` .

If this also doesn't fix it, run an [inplace upgrade to repair Windows](https://superuser.com/a/637869/174557).

Comment: which KB number was it? Maybe this helps other users, too.